# Google Exchange Rates build

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

I am trying to make a currency exchange rate Google sheet. I want a cell to give me a value of conversion based on the value of another cell. Currency type can be selected from the Dropdown List and then value under it. Kindly help to make this formula.

[My Google Currency Exchange Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vnd96rnjk0tC8_Jo_mlkAORRyuVT1up9fzWdYrjxG78/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IFERROR($C5*GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:"&$C4&D6), $C5)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: You did, Magic! Thank you, Man!